# How to create a spreadsheet look alike order form in Access 2007 that will have all my products listed

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

How to create a spreadsheet look alike order form in Access 2007. 
I want all my products listed from my products table, lets say in the first column and to have a  quantity field  in the second column. The user will type in amount required for each product. Once finished the data needs to be saved in Orderdetails table with all the products and quantity required. It should also save an OrderID for this order.
I have a main form that has the following fields:
OrderId, OrderDate, OrderRequired, ShopName, Notes.

In my subform I would like to have the spreadsheet look alike form where the customer can choose the products needed and save it to Orderdetails Table referenced by OrderID.
I don't want the user to pick one product at a time, but to be able to see all products and the qty for each product by its side.

Please help to get me on the right direction
Sassoon

Comment: Have you looked at the form wizards?

Comment: My Problem is how to have a quantity field for each product that is not in my products table. But I would like to save it to a orderdetails table all the products with the qty field showing how many for each product including the 0 quantities. I can create a datasheet but I can't add a qty field. I want to have excel look a like form with blanks for qty for each product. Once the order has been finished I would like to save it to a table.

Comment: My orderform has about 120 products showing in a datasheet form.          ProductId, ProductName, QtyRequired.  Once the order has been completed in the datasheet, I need to save it to my OrderDetails Table That has all the fields as my Orderform above with added field OrderID so that I can reference it to when the order was done and to which shop.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but this sounds very much like a standard many-to-many structured table, which would be linked to products, users and quantities.

You can make field and record selections by creating a saved query and display this one on a form that the user accesses directly.
If you don't want that, use textboxes and buttons and perform the inserts / updates yourself...

Edit: 
What I believe you may be looking for is a function called "Lookup Wizard".
When you create your many-to-many structured table, create a foreign key to the "product" table via this wizard. The wizard allows the user to see the linked products in a dropdown list on selection.
In the same table, also create other fields (foreign keys when needed) to Trays, packets and ProductNotes.

Another way would be to offer the product list via filling a combobox with data from the product table.

```
sSQL_Select = "SELECT * FROM T_PRODUCTS" 

Me.lstListBox.RowSource = "" 
Me.lstListBox.RowSource = sSQL_Select
```

You can do the same for Trays, packets and productnotes and upload the data by creating your customized SQL string.
It is possible to show a read-only subform table in a form if you don't want users to mess around with them.

Comment: This option still gives me 1 product at a time on the order form. I need to list all the products on the order form and next to each product to have 3 empty fields for Trays, packets and ProductNotes. Once the order is done to save to a table. I can't seem to find a solution for this.